# Why do edits need to be approved by two users?

Tags: discussion

When reviewing suggested edits, if one clicks <kbd>Approve</kbd>, another user still has to approve it before it goes live.

**However, if one clicks <kbd>Improve Edit</kbd>, the edit is instantly applied without needing a 2nd review.**

So I ask, why does a normal approve need two reviews?

Comment: I guess it's because `Approve` requires the reviewer just a single click and not much thought, whereas `Improve Edit` requires actually some work and the reviewer has to think about what they do. That way the system probably prevents robo-reviewing.

Comment: If you improve an edit, you've given it at least two looks :)

Comment: @ByteCommander I would say that classifies as an answer...

Comment: @Fabby There you have it.

Answer (score 19):

It's because <kbd>Approve</kbd> requires the reviewer just a single click and not much thought, whereas <kbd>Improve Edit</kbd> actually requires some work and the reviewer has to think about what they do.

This is one of the ways how the system prevents robo-reviewing.

Related reading material from Meta.SE:

- [It takes two to tango?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151536/280883)
- [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76251/280883)

Comment: You also get your name stamped on the post. No one wants their name stamped on top of a bad edit. That's almost as bad as making the edit yourself.